# Divine Defiance Feat Mechanics: Spell Slot Expenditure Clarification

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, counterspelling

Regarding the Divine Defiance feat from *Fiendish Codex II: Tyrants of the Nine Hells* (p. 83), the text states:

> You can spend one of your turn or rebuke undead attempts as an immediate action to counter a spell or spelllike effect. For example, if an evil cleric targets Jozan with a *hold person* spell, as an immediate action, Jozan can spend a turn undead attempt to counter the spell if he had prepared a *hold person* or *dispel magic* spell. You must have the relevant spell prepared as normal (or *dispel magic*), and you must make a Spellcraft check to identify the target's spell if applicable.

The feat requires having the relevant spell prepared, but it doesn't explicitly mention spending the spell slot. Does using Divine Defiance consume the spell slot, or is it only the turn or rebuke undead attempt that is expended?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### You still have to cast the spell.

The benefit of Divine Defiance is that you don’t have to ready a (standard) action in order to counter a spell. Instead you only need an Immediate Action, and can react/decide spontaneously whether you want to cast a counterspell or not, which is a great advantage.

The benefit text ends with an important line:

> (See PH 170 for details on counterspells.)

This means that the process of counterspelling works just like it normally does – apart from the changes mentioned above. You have to cast the correct spell to complete the action.

Comment: Divine Defiance is a “great advantage” over usual counterspelling, but for what it’s with, still not a really great strategy in my experience.